# how can i read credit card through NFC in flutter and make mobile to act as NFC card for other mobile

Tags: flutter, dart, nfc, payment, mobile-application

I need some information and advise totally based on flutter. First of all how can I read Credit Card or bank card through NFC in Flutter than use information or transaction.
I used some packages but that give me blank information.

Second one how can I make Mobile to react as an NFC card for other mobile in flutter

These packages I already use But not help me out
flutter_nfc_kit: ^2.2.0
flutter_nfc_reader: ^0.1.0